# Facebook like buttons sometimes don't work

Tags: facebook

I am a newbie in Facebook programming. This is how I put like buttons on a single page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href='@site1.Url'>@site1.Title</<a>
            <fb:like href="site1.Url"></fb:like>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href='@site2.Url'>@site2.Title</<a>
            <fb:like href="@site2.Url"></fb:like>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The like buttons appear and all looks good. But sometimes I can't actually like.
Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href='@site1.Url'>@site1.Title</<a>
            <fb:like href="@site1.Url"></fb:like>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href='@site2.Url'>@site2.Title</<a>
            <fb:like href="@site2.Url"></fb:like>
        </div>
        <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is like the code that http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ gives you. But the problem remains in my code.

Comment: The thing about the code from the document is that you insure the `xfbml` support is acquired when the JS library is loaded. Now for the sites that are not "liked" check those sites for errors. Also try to run then on the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to check for problems.

Comment: Here is the site  [I can't like](http://skulibj.net76.net/Likes/Like3.html]).
I get warnings from the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) but I just get the same warnings as for my other pages that [I can like](http://skulibj.net76.net/Likes/Like4.html)

Comment: @Skúli: I can like both links from the Linter, try to use the iframe version for instance also try adding the required meta tags.

Comment: @ifaour do you know what the purpose of the <div id="fb-root"> is?

Comment: @Skúli: It's used by Facebook scripts loaded by `all.js`. For iframe manipulation..etc. Open the js file and try searching for `fb-root`

Comment: Ok. That is probably the problem I was facing. I would like to verify that. In any case my code in the answer is wrong. It lacks div#fb-root and probably the script should not be loaded until after the like buttons, so, thats probably my problem.